# Spring batch without pojo or Dao

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am asking the same question again as I got no aswears yesterday.

I am new spring batch. I have customized the spring batch examplefor spring boot.

My problem is: I want to write the code file upload, read and save in database in such a way that irrespective of .csv file I should be able to do it without need of any addition.

This means possibly No POJO. Generic rowmapper.
User will upload a file that will have headers and those should be used to create the dynamic update/insert query.

While there are many basic tools on web, I want to use spring batch for its additional features.

Is it possible? I tried my besg find it but could not find on web or manual and here is a proof as well. Not sure if the situation is changed. 
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/78702-flatfile-to-db-without-pojo

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Don't ask the same question over and over.